# How to optimise Rcpp function (calling another R function)

Tags: c++, r, optimization, rcpp, microbenchmark

I'm solving the following problem: Given two vectors `x`,`y` and a vectorised function `f`. I'd like to compute for each element `x0` of `x` the average of `f(x_0 - y)`.

I already implemented the function in R like this

```
sol <- function(x, y, f) {
  ret <- numeric(length(x))
  for (y0 in y) {
    ret <- ret + f(x - y0)
  }
  ret/length(y)
}
```

We could use the function like this `sol(1:100, 1:100, exp)`. Since this function is a crucial part of my code I'd like to optimise it. The length of `x` is in the range (1 - 100,000) and `y` is in the range (1 - 1,000). I tried using Rcpp like this

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('NumericVector cppEval(NumericVector x, NumericVector y, Function f) {
  int num_y = y.size();
  
  NumericVector out(x.size());
  for(int i = 0; i < num_y; ++i) {
    out += Rcpp::as<NumericVector>(f(x - y[i]));
  }
  
  return out/num_y;
}')
```

Sadly this piece of code is much slower than the R equivalent. What could I do to efficiently write Cpp here? I don't know how to completely get rid of the loop.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sol(1:100, 1:100, exp), cppEval(1:100, 1:100, exp))
Unit: microseconds
                       expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
     sol(1:100, 1:100, exp)  157.572  178.336  244.4421  210.4775  221.7085  4199.367   100
 cppEval(1:100, 1:100, exp) 1451.395 1628.367 1829.2443 1697.7480 1794.4390 12868.237   100
```

Comment: You need to implement your function in Rcpp. A call to an R closure is expensive, regardless if you do it from R or Rcpp. The latter even creates additional overhead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rcpp function to be SLOWER than same R function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17958168/rcpp-function-to-be-slower-than-same-r-function)